# JSON & Array get data with PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a question about some JSON and PHP, see json below.
How can I get the number string?

```
 {
   ”data”: [
   {
     ”numbers”: [
      {
        ”number”: "XXXX",
        ”type”: ””
      }
      ]
   }
  ]
 }
```

Ive tried with the following but its not working:
$item['numbers'][0]->number;

Note, the $item array is ok. I just do not know what is wrong here.

EDIT:

I should point out that there was an json_decode before.
So the structure looks like this:

```
 Array
 (
  [0] => Array
    (
        [number] => XXXX
        [type] => 
    )
 )

 print_r($item['numbers']);
```

This doesn't work: $item['numbers'][0]['number'];
Error:  Undefined offset: 0 in

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried accessing as '$item['data']['numbers']['number']' ?

Comment: @AdrianMcCool Hope my post will help you out.. You were accessing the wrong way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to direct access then use this code

```
$items->data->numbers->number;
```

you can use php `json_decode()`.it takes a JSON encoded string and converts it into a PHP variable.

```
<?php
$json_data = '{
   "data": [
   {
     "numbers": [
      {
        "number": "11",
        "Type": ""
      }
      ]
   }
  ]
 }';
$array=json_decode($json_data,true);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo $array["data"][0]["numbers"][0]["number"];
```

then output

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [numbers] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [number] => 11
                                    [Type] => 
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
Number:11
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the number try this :

```
$myJSON->data->numbers->number;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `json_decode()` function of PHP.

```
$array = json_decode('{
   ”data”: [
   {
     ”numbers”: [
      {
        ”number”: "",
        ”Type”: ””
      }
      ]
   }
  ]
 }', true);
```

Then you could access it as $array["data"]["numbers"]["number"];

Comment: Updated the source code so it would return Array not Class. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: There is already a json_decode thrown at it. What you see is after the json_encode.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you out... You are trying to access which does not actually exists.

[**try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/783702)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$month_options = '{
   "data": [
   {
     "numbers": [
      {
        "number": "10",
        "Type": ""
      }
      ]
   }
  ]
 }';
$array=json_decode($month_options,true);
echo $array["data"][0]["numbers"][0]["number"];
```